# Relational Algebra for Cartesian product without duplicates

Tags: relational-algebra, cartesian-product, cross-product

I have a relation A:

```
    key | value
    -----------
     a  |  2
     b  |  2
     c  |  9
     d  |  5
     e  |  3
```

If I perform a cross product on itself twice, I'll get triplets such as (a,b,a), (a,a,a), (a,a,b), (b,c,b), etc. I'm interested in removing all tuples such that no key appears more than once in the output.

First, is there a relational algebra statement for this? Second, is it possible to generalize this scenario to multiple cross products (i.e., `n` cross products)?

Comment: Please clarify "removing all tuples such that no key appears more than once in the output".

Answer (score 2):

Cross product (usually just called *product*) is a join of two relations having no attributes in common. You can't make the product of A with itself unless you rename the attributes of A to create a new relation. The product would then consist of the distinct set of attributes from both relations. Product always results in a relation with distinct tuples just like any other relational algebra operation.

Your questions are a bit unclear. The tri-tuples in your example don't include the value attribute so I don't understand which tuples you would expect to appear in the output. Perhaps your first question could be rephrased as *"Is there a relational algebra operation which joins each tuple from one relation to exactly one arbitrary tuple in another without me having to specify what to join on?"*. No such operation exists because no formal system can make the decision for you about which subset of tuples should be in the result. Hopefully that answer is "obvious" but if you make your question more specific then maybe someone can give a more specific answer.

Regarding your second question. Yes, product generalizes very simply to any number of operations and is commutative and associative. The mathematical definition of product is that it is a binary operation but it's easy to imagine a similar relational operation taking any number of relations as its operands.